# What is wrong with parsing the ls command ?

Tags: bash, ls

I have been told that it is unwise to parse the output of LS due to security precautions.

The adage used was "parse sparsely and dont eat parsley"

I was attempting to count the amount of files within a directory by using

```
ls -la | wc -l
```

I was told to never, never do this but I cant grasp why.

I was told one reason is because a file name could be shuffled into another command by accident. For example, if a file was within the directory named '-l'.

I was also told about using '--', for example ls -la --. If I understand correctly this is supposed to tell bash where to signal the end of commands but even if you used this you still shouldn't parse the output of ls.

Why ?

Comment: If it's only counting you can do it safely with `ls -qa | wc -l` but then, there are better ways to count items in a directory.

Comment: the problem with "why not parse LS" is the answers are so complicated I cant get anything out of them

Comment: Don can you share the better way to count items in a directory? I'm assuming its with the find command?

Comment: Search the site for "count files in a directory"...

Comment: The [Bash Wooledge](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) page on it is a bit more clear.  And [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/135943) is fairly relevant, also.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Also, the comments on the other question are much clearer than the answers.  To quote one of these: "You have a stream of text produced by `ls` that can contain *any* bytes except the null byte or the slash. There is fundamentally no way to recover that into a list of filenames. The transformation `ls` does is non-reversible, even if it doesn't replace any nonprintable characters. When it replaces non-printable characters, you're in an even worse situation."

Comment: Thank you. The "why not parse ls" post has a comment that says basically the answer is too complicated and it has 46 upvotes. I added my vote there also. I will read these links you provided.